# XCTest | lexical or preprocessor issue: MyProject-Swift.h not found

Tags: objective-c, swift, xcode, xctest, bridging-header

My project uses for both Objective C and Swift (primarily Objcective C).

Importing HomeViewController.h in a test class, 
HomeViewController imports MyProject-Swift.h to access the swift files.

The build fails whenever I run the tests.
The main target is running fine.

[image]

Comment: have you added `@testable <ProjectName>` in your test file?

Comment: Writing tests in Objective C, it doest require such has no such access modifiers.

Comment: @DeepakRajput Please check the answer and accept if it resolves your issue.

Answer (score 1):

Make sure your **.m** file is a member of your test target.
Click on **.m** file and click on file inspector to see it. If it's missing 
That will through an error. Also, compile sources of your test target should have all **.m** files (the one you are testing) in Build Phases.
[image]